# Avalonia. DataGrid: How to set the color of a cell depending on its content?

Tags: c#, .net-core, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a DataGrid with auto-generated columns. How to correctly change the color of a cell depending on its content: an empty cell, a cell with a value, etc? I found information only about editing the entire row.

Comment: Hi. Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [Take a Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [What and How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, [post a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Styles`. For a `DataGridCell`, this would look like:

```xml
<DataGrid.Styles>
    <Style Selector="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" 
                Value="{Binding IsDirty, Converter={StaticResource IsDirtyColorConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Styles>
```